# How to integrate aar library dependency in eclipse for android project

Tags: android, eclipse, aar

I have develop one library project using android studio [with gradle]. Now i want to integrate my library project in my main project.
I have successfully integrate this project in android studio using maven. But i don't know how to integrate this library project with my main project using eclise IDE. I have search many times in google as well stackoverflow but not found any solution.

So please give me any hint or solution.

Comment: Why do you want to use Eclipse? It really isn't built for AAR files or a good option for modern Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Hi As you may know android studio structure is different from eclipse project. if you want to move studio to eclipse there are lots gradle dependencies files generated by android studio, that eclipse never used this files & even eclipse can not understand these all files.

The simplest way is just create the android project in eclipse and copy all your resources directory files( inside you values directory & drawable if you used ) and source files with the keeping the package structure you have in library project & mark the project as library in your project-> properties under the android tab checked the project as library.

In short you have to manually convert the project in eclipse there is not other options for directly convert the studio project in to eclipse.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for respond , I don't want to convert studio project into eclipse I just used this project as library project.

Comment: You can use only use this library in android studio if you want to the same project in android studio you have to follow the step i suggested to you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can to link aar library as separate project(type this project as library) and make dependence into main project.